# How to make my user input allow for variables in it in python?

Tags: python, string, variables, input

My problem is that my program will not recognize the user input for the sides of the equation includes a variable in it (x) which I am using a trial and error method for finding. It sees x as a string, seperate from the defined variable x. So, if the user put in for the right side of the equation 16 and x*x for the left side, the program won't recognize x as the variable x, but as a string x. PLEASE HELP. Anyway, here is my code, (it is mean to solve for an equation with only one variable type, x):

```
startingLimit=raw_input("What is the lowest estimate that your variable could possibly be?")

print

wholeNumber=raw_input("Do you know if your variable will be a whole number or a             fraction? Answer: yes/no")
if (wholeNumber== "yes"):
    print
    fraction= raw_input("Is it a decimal/fraction? Answer:yes/no")
if (fraction=="yes"):
    print
    print "This program will only calculate up to the fourth place to the right of the decimal"
    xfinder=0.0001
else:
    xfinder=1

x=4          
leftEquation=raw_input("Enter your left side of the equation:")
print
rightEquation=raw_input("Enter the right side of the equation:")
print
amountSolutions=raw_input("How many solutions are there to your equation? (up to 20)")




indivisualCount=0
count=0

while (count!=amountSolutions):


if (count==1):
    if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        a=x
        count=count+1
if (count==2):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        b=x
        count=count+1
if (count==3):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        c=x
        count=count+1
if (count==4):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        d=x
        count=count+1
if (count==5):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        e=x
        count=count+1
if (count==6):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        f=x
        count=count+1
if (count==7):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        g=x
        count=count+1
if (count==8):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        h=x
        count=count+1
if (count==9):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        i=x
        count=count+1
if (count==10):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        j=x
        count=count+1
if (count==11):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        k=x
        count=count+1
if (count==12):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        l=x
        count=count+1
if (count==13):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        m=x
        count=count+1
if (count==14):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        n=x
        count=count+1
if (count==15):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        o=x
        count=count+1
if (count==16):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        p=x
        count=count+1
if (count==17):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        q=x
        count=count+1
if (count==18):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        r=x
        count=count+1
if (count==19):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        s=x
        count=count+1
if (count==20):
     if (leftEquation==rightEquation):
        t=x


if (indivisualCount==0):
    x=x+xfinder
    indivisualCount=indivisualCount+1

x=x+xfinder



print
print "Compiling..."
time.sleep(3)
if (amountSolutions==1):
    print "Solutions= ",a
if (amountSolutions==2):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b
if (amountSolutions==3):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c
if (amountSolutions==4):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d
if (amountSolutions==5):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e
if (amountSolutions==6):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f
if (amountSolutions==7):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g
if (amountSolutions==8):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
if (amountSolutions==9):
   print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
if (amountSolutions==10):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k
if (amountSolutions==11):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l
if (amountSolutions==12):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m
if (amountSolutions==13):
    print "Solutions=",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n
if (amountSolutions==15):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,u,j,k,l,m,n,o
if (amountSolutions==16):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,u,j,k,l,m,n,o,p
if (amountSolutions==17):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,u,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q
if (amountSolutions==18):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,u,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r
if (amountSolutions==19):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,u,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s
if (amountSolutions==20):
    print "Solutions= ",a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,u,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t


print
print
time.sleep(5)
print "PROGRAM COMPLETED"
```

Comment: Some unrelated advice: you should learn about loops (`for count in range(amountSolutions)`) and lists (`solutions = []` and `solutions.append(newsolution)`).  Your code right now has a *lot* of repetition, and that's almost always a sign that you need to think about the problem one level up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) to evaluate arbitrary Python code. It is generally a Very Bad Idea to use this in real world code as it is extremely dangerous to allow users to execute unknown code, even if you try to restrict what they can do.

However, if you *do* use it, I *strongly* encourage you to use the `globals` and `locals` arguments to restrict the variables users are allowed to use. An example:

```
>>> x=5
>>> eval('x*x', None, {'x': x})
25
```

By explicitly only defining the variable x you ensure the user doesn't try to access things they're not supposed to:

```
>>> eval('x*y', None, {'x': x})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

If you want to allow math functions to be used you can pass them in the 2nd argument like so:

```
>>> import math
>>> eval('sin(x)', {'sin': math.sin}, {'x': x})
-0.95892427466313845
```